# Eclipse - programaticaly highlight multiple lines of an editor

Tags: java, eclipse, google-maps-markers

I'm currently trying to highlight multiple lines of an editor (they might not be one after the other - i.e comments spread throughout a source file). I've been able to programmatically open an editor and highlight one line with -

```
IDE.openEditor(page, m);
```

where `m` is an IMarker.

My question is how can I programmatically (in Java) select multiple lines. You can assume I have relevant markers for each line I wish to be highlighted and therefore all the relevant information (lineNum etc.)

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to write a _plugin_ for Eclipse?

Comment: @Abra yes, currently adapting the plantuml plugin.

Comment: @greg-449 can you clarify on your point a bit? Im finding it difficult to understand what you mean

Comment: This is a very complex area and I no longer remember the details. Eclipse editors define several extension points to let you define how markers and other annotations are shown. But you need to know exactly what the editor you are targeting supports.

Answer (score 0):

Right so I've figured it out - thanks to @greg-449

Heres is an article which greatly helped - http://cubussapiens.hu/2011/05/custom-markers-and-annotations-the-bright-side-of-eclipse/

So effectivly you have to define a custom marker in the plugin.xml file along with a custom annotation for it;

```
<extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.annotationTypes">
   <type
         markerType="FSM.MARKER"
         name="FSM.MARKER">
   </type>
</extension>

<extension
        id="FSM.MARKER"
        name="FSM.MARKER"
        point="org.eclipse.core.resources.markers">
    <super
        type="org.eclipse.core.resources.textmarker">
    </super>
</extension>

<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.markerAnnotationSpecification">
  <specification
        annotationType="FSM.MARKER"
        colorPreferenceKey="FSM.MARKER.COLOR"
        colorPreferenceValue="0,125,255"
        contributesToHeader="false"
        highlightPreferenceKey="FSM.MARKER.highlight"
        highlightPreferenceValue="true"
        includeOnPreferencePage="true"
        label="FSM.MARKER"
        overviewRulerPreferenceKey="org.eclipse.viatra2.slice.overview"
        overviewRulerPreferenceValue="true"
        presentationLayer="0"
        textPreferenceKey="org.eclipse.viatra2.slice.text"
        textPreferenceValue="true"
        textStylePreferenceValue="BOX"
        verticalRulerPreferenceKey="org.eclipse.viatra2.slice.ruler"
        verticalRulerPreferenceValue="true">
   </specification>
</extension>
```

And then in your code you can create a custom marker with;

```
IMarker marker = root.createMarker("FSM.MARKER");
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, lineNum);
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.SOURCE_ID, path);
//if (region.getOffset() != 0) {
       marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_START,charStart);
       marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_END,charEnd);
```

Which produces the following kind of annotation;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzXmH.png)